# Prove the Restriction of F to D is a function from D to E

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading my teacher's solution to this problem, and this part of the proof is confusing to me:

Let f: A->B, $D\subseteq A$ and E = f(D).

Suppose $x\in D$. Since $D\subseteq A$, then $x \in A$. Since f:A->B, then f(x) is already defined. Hence, $(x, f(x))\in f|_{D}$ .

Specifically, the last sentence befuddles me. How can you assume that $(x, f(x))\in f|_{D}$ ? Is it because of the definition of restriction functions, where $f|_{D}$={(x,y): y=f(x) and$x\in D$}
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty trivial. $x \in D$ and $y=f(x)$ tells us that $y \in f[D]=E$ so $(x,y) \subseteq D \times E$, in fact:

$$(D \times f[D]) \cap f = f\restriction_D$$

as sets of pairs.